# How to prevent this error from happening? (NODEJS Bcryptjs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bcrypt

I created a user update controller in my application, but the problem is that when testing this in postman, I can't just send information that I want to edit without having to pass the password along, which is being rendered asynchronously with the bcryptjs

error:

```
Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, string
    at Object.bcrypt.hashSync (/home/pc/api_foodelivery/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:189:19)
    at exports.update (/home/pc/api_foodelivery/src/controllers/UserController/UpdateUser.js:16:37)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

```
const db = require('../../models/index');

const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

exports.update = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const { firstName, lastName, email, password, phoneNumber } = req.body;
    try {

        const user = await db.User.findOne({ where: { id } });

        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).json('User does not exist');
        }

        const hashPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 8);

        await user.update({
            firstName,
            lastName,
            email,
            password: hashPassword,
            phoneNumber,
        });

        return res.status(200).json('User updated!');
    } catch (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
}
```

From what I understand, this error occurs because I am not passing anything to my hashPassword, but how can I make this not mandatory when updating my database user?

Comment: Seems like you didn't pass `password` prop in `req.body`. Add the similar check as you did for `user` using 401 status

Comment: And I see no link with Sequelize here (looking at stacktrace)

Comment: Every time I edit my user database, am I required to pass the password too? Even if I just want to edit an email?

Comment: It seems like you need to add authentication, for instance using JWT. That way a route to update user should be authenticated prior to get to the route code for updating a user

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. I have a token virification function to be able to update but the issue is the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

```
const db = require('../../models/index');

const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

exports.update = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const { firstName, lastName, email, password, phoneNumber } = req.body;
    try {

        const user = await db.User.findOne({ where: { id } });

        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).json('User does not exist');
        }

        // You need to check here if user wants to update password or not
        const updatedUser = {
            firstName,
            lastName,
            email,
            phoneNumber
        } // You may further check for every filed if not undefined here

        if(password && password !== "") {
            const hashPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 8);
            updatedUser.password = hashPassword
        }


        await user.update(updatedUser);

        return res.status(200).json('User updated!');
    } catch (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
}
```